# How do I check if an int is even

Tags: java, int, integer-arithmetic

This is likely an easy solution that is simply eluding me.  Specifically, I am creating locations on a canvas dynamically using a sin() function for equidistant points on a circle.  Once these points are created, I am animating a shape moving from one point to the next by calculating the slope between points and redrawing the shape at each slope step.

Problem is, depending on the coordinate values, the slope step may just be one step from point a to point b.  I need the shape to move along the path, not just jump point to point.

What I want to do is force the location coordinates (x, y) to be even numbers allowing for slope values to always be reducible.  So, the simple part of question is...

How do I check if an int value is even?  If it is not, I will simply add 1 to the coordinate value.

Comment: It is not clear why you could not move the shape along the path by moving it just one unit. Generally, you should avoid playing games or trick with coordinates to force the values into your math. The math should work naturally. However, you have not given enough details to evaluate this.

Comment: I am animating packet movements on a simulated network in Java.
Nodes are represented with PointShapes of Location(int x, int y)
Packets are represented by RectangleShapes starting at a source Node location and being moved along a network link to the destination Node location.  I need to display the movement, not just disappearing from one Node and appearing at the other Node.

I'm new to this, obviously, and this is my first attempt at writing a program outside of class.  I apologize for any possible vagueness of my questions.

Answer (score 1):

```
int newNumber = someInt % 2 == 0 ? someInt : someInt + 1;
```

Comment: So...
int isEven = xcoord % 2;
if(isEven == 0) would mean xcoord is an even number?

Comment: or more simply
if(xcoord%2 == 0)

Comment: @DanielWhitlock: Please never set `isEven = xcoord % 2`. This results in something called `isEven` being “false” if the value is even. The name should match the meaning. You could use `remainder = xcoord % 2` or `isOdd = xcoord % 2`.

Comment: Okay, so just set a remainder value to the mod of 2 and then check the remainder value against 0 right?

Answer (score 1):

To see if an integer is even:

1. Check if its value is congruent to 0 modulo 2. That is `value MOD 2 == 0`. In C-style languages this is usually expressed as `value % 2 == 0`.
2. Alternatively, check the value of bit 0. That is `value BITWISE-AND 0x01 == 0`. In C-style languages this is usually expressed as `(value & 0x01) == 0`.

If you do not care which direction you round, you can even-ize an integer in a single operation by taking its value bitwise-and a mask of `0xFFFE` (of course padded to the width of your integer), which will force set the 0 bit to zero. That is `value := value BITWISE-AND 0xFFFE`, or in C-style languages `value &= 0xFFFE`.

Answer (score 0):

Do a mod 2 on it.  If the remainder is 0, it's an even number.

VB:

Dim even = (3 mod 2 = 0 )

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give you specifics since you haven't given many, but you should look into the 
[Modulo operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).

Comment: Yea, I apologize, very new to this forum.  I'm trying to get the hang of it.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

For integers, while using modulo will give you the correct answer, it requires division. Division isn't as fast as bitwise operations. For what you need, a bitwise AND is sufficient.

```
if(x & 0x1)
{
   sdt::cout << "x is odd" << std::endl;
}
else
{
   std::cout << "x is even" << std::endl;
}
```

The key is that all positive powers of two are even. Therefore the only way a binary representation of an integer can be odd is if the first bit is set.